# uncaughtException SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode in sparkpost modules

Tags: node.js, sparkpost

> {"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException SyntaxError: Use of
>   const in strict mode.\n    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)\n
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)\n    at
>   Module.load (module.js:356:32)\n    at Function.Module._load
>   (module.js:312:12)\n    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)\n    at
>   require (module.js:380:17)\n    at Object.
>   (/var/www/myproject/dist/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/lib/index.js:5:33)\n
>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)\n    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)\n    at Module.load
>   (module.js:356:32)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)\n 
>   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)\n    at require
>   (module.js:380:17)\n    at Object.
>   (/var/www/myproject/dist/node_modules/sparkpost/node_modules/request/request.js:9:12)\n
>   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)\n    at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js
>   (module.js:474:10)","timestamp":"2017-09-25T02:45:43.418Z"}

I've found that problem when I run my node backend project. I didn't upgrade anything in these days and encounter that error accidentally.

My node version is `node -v v0.10.37 npm -v 1.4.28` Please help me how to solve that issue. Thanks.

Comment: Try to force strict mode `node --use_strict your-script.js`

Comment: While `--use_strict` will likely let you use `const` in strict mode code, you might find other issues caused by your very old version of Node.js. [According to the readme](https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost#installation), the `sparkpost` module requires Node.js v4 and above. You could either upgrade your Node.js version or downgrade to `sparkpost` [v1.3.8](https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost/tree/1.3.8).